# How to monitor Nvidia GPU computation/memory usage on GCP Stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, monitoring, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to monitor Nvidia GPU computaion/memory usage on Google Cloud Platform.
CPU usage can be monitored by default at the GCP web console, but I need Stackdriver agent to monitor RAM usage (as far as I know).

My compute engine instance has (preemptive) GPU(s).
I could get the current GPU usage by running `nvidia-smi` command, but I have no idea how to let stackdriver know these metrics.

Comment: Did you consider creating a custom metric and then loading it with t he result of nvidia-smi? https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics

Comment: Did you try creating the custom metric as suggested by @MattWilbert? If you did, is it providing the results you expect? If not, provide a detailed message of the issue you are receiving.